# Replace value all attributes XML by input text using XSLT maintaining XML identation

Tags: xml, xslt

From this example XML:

```
<?**xml** version='*1.0*' encoding='*UTF-8*' ?>
<**config**>
  <**Connections**>
    <**DbMetaData** tablePrefix="*example.*"/>
    <**AGSConnection**
                  outputDirectory="*C:\directory2\directories\isoutput*"                  virtualOutputDirectory="*https://directory1.example1.net/ex/rest/output*"/>
    <**SDEConnection**
                  server="*srv01*" 
                  instance="*sde:sqlserver:srv01*" 
                  database="*DBex*" 
                  authenticationMode="*DBMS*"
                  user="*user1*" 
                  password="*pass123*" 
                  version="*sde.DEFAULT*"
                  sdeConnectionPath="*C:\\tmp\\ex\\conexion\\ser01.sde*"/>
 </**Connections**>
 </**config**>
```

And using XSLT, replace all attribute values by editable text fields, maintaining the indentation (XML structure). How could I get something like this?:

[final result in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT95Z.png)

thanks,

Comment: **1.** Please post the expected result **as code**. -- **2.** What is the meaning of all the asterisks in your input?

Comment: Here, what you meant say for "editable text fields" in the XML output result

Comment: By "keeping indentation", do you also mean all the extra spaces between e.g. `outputDirectory` and `virtualOutputDirectory`? From xml perspective they are irrelevant and xslt processors will strip them - but using anything else but xml-aware applications is neither a _good_ solution

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to guess what you mean: you just want to replace the attribute values with "some input".

In xslt, you can pass "some input" by either a separate xml document that you read using the `document()` function, or you can use parameters to pass values into the stylesheet like that: (modified identity transform with extra templates for the to-be-replaced attributes)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="tablePrefix" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="outputDirectory" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="virtualOutputDirectory" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="server" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="instance" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="database" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="authenticationMode" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="user" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="password" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="version" select="''"/>
<xsl:param name="sdeConnectionPath"/>
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>  
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@tablePrefix">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$tablePrefix != ''">
                <xsl:attribute name="tablePrefix">
                    <xsl:value-of select="$tablePrefix"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- repeat for each of the attributes replacing all "tablePrefix" by the attribute -->

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How you pass the params depends on your xslt processor, e.g. `--stringparam name value` with xsltproc or `-param name value` with xalanj.

Answer (score 0):

The XML parser doesn't tell the XSLT processor how much whitespace there was between the attributes, so once the data is in XSLT, this information is lost. You can get the XSLT processor to do its own indentation of the output using `<xsl:output indent='yes'/>`, but it won't necessarily be the same as the original. (For what it's worth, the indentation in your input, if we ignore the strange asterisks, looks as if it was produced using Saxon.)